# What is the meaning of font-family?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm a beginner in HTML and CSS. I am confused about the `font-family` property.

I declare `font-family` as follows:

```
{
    font-family:cambria, sans-serif, georgia;
}
```

But when I remove the `sans-serif, georgia` part, the visual appearance stays the same.

Why declare the `font-family` and how it is differ from `font`?

Comment: [`font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font) is a shorthand of dozens of `font-*` properties including `line-height` :-) one of them is `font-family`.

Comment: Thank you @Bram Vanroy for useful editing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `font` declaration is a **shorthand** allowing us to style `font-size`, `font-weight`, `font-family`, `font-variant` and `line-height`. all in one. (Just like how `background` is a shorthand for `background-color`, `background-url`, `background-image` and several other background-related properties.)

`font-family` itself allows us to specify an initial font, and generic fonts which get used in case the initial font cannot be used. In your case, `cambria` is the initial font, `sans-serif` is the fallback font style used if a user's system does not have the `cambria` font, and `georgia` is used if no `sans-serif` fonts exist on the user's system.

Comment: Pedantically, font resolution is not done on a does-the-browser-have-the-font basis but per character, i.e. On a does-the-font-if-it-is-available-have-the-character basis. So for example, a character can come from the sans-serif font if that character is not defined in the cambria font, even if the browser has the cambria font available.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
font-family:cambria, sans-serif, georgia;
}
```

mean :
if your browser does not support `cambria` use `sans-serif` if not support `sans-serif` use `georgia` also if not support `georgia` it will show default font

```
Font: 12px bold cambria, sans-serif;
```

mean : font-size / font-weight / font-family

Answer (score 3):

You list the fonts in order of desire. The page will try to load with cambria, but if the user doesn't have cambria it will try ANY sans-serif font, and lastly it will try georgia.

Imagine if you were using a very specific font that all users might not have, you'd want to provide a backup so that the system default font doesn't appear in the event the user doesn't have your first desired font.

Comment: Not ANY sans-serif font but a browser-specific sans-serif font, and there is no trying after that, since the generic sans-serif font always exists.

Answer (score 2):

Its a prioritized list; try to use the first font, if its not available try the second and so on.

`font {}` encompasses `font-family` in that its a way to set several `font-*` values in a single pass, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).

Answer (score 2):

When using font-family, you are declaring specifically the type of font you are going to use. On the other hand, using just the 'font' attribute, you can declare various font styling attributes.

```
Font-Family: cambria, sans-serif, georgia;
```

Doing this tells the browser that you prefer to use 'cambria' font, if that font does not exist in this browser though, you would like to use 'sans-serif', and so on.

```
Font: 12px bold cambria, sans-serif;
```

This allows you to put multiple values in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Font family is a list, if the first font you specify cannot be displayed the 2nd font will be loaded, and if the 2nd font can't be loaded  the 3rd one will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

The font-family is a CSS property that accepts a prioritized list of font family names that specifies the font for an element. It can take values that are separated by a comma to indicate that they are alternatives if the first font that is indicated on the list is not available on the browser.

```
{
font-family: cambria, sans-serif, georgia;
}
```

It means that if the font "cambria" is not available on the browser it will choose "sans-serif" and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

The [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) property specifies the list of font families to be tried, in preference order. It does not affect other font-related properties, except that the choice affects the meaning of `normal` for `line-height` (which is font- and browser-dependent).

In contrast, using the `font` shorthand property always sets *all* font-related properties, though only font size and font family need to be explicitly specified, e.g. `font: 1em Cambria`; other properties will then be set to their initial values.

The value of `font-family` is used so that for each character in the element content, the first font family in the list is used, if a) the font family is available in the user’s system *and* b) the applicable font in that family contains a glyph for the character. (This is the defined mechanism, but browsers are known to implement it partly incorrectly.)

In the example case, if the user’s system has Cambria and it contains glyphs for all characters in the relevant elements, the other values in the `font-family` value have no effect. If there is a character that is not present in Cambria but is present in the font used by the browser as the generic `sans-serif` font, then the latter is used—possibly creating a stylistic mismatch. (Generally, serif fonts like Cambria should have serif fallbacks.) The `georgia` part would matter only in the very unlikely case where the system has Georgia but lacks Cambria *and* the browser’s default `sans-serif` font does not contain some character in the content but Georgia does.

Whether you use `font-family` (and other specific font properties) or the `font` shorthand, or both, is a matter of judgment and taste. Conceptually, it is much simpler to set all font properties separately. In terms of code length, `font` can save you some byes.

Comment: Always an elaborate answer.